# JButton size larger than specified

Tags: java, swing

I created a `jframe`, added a `jbutton` to it, and set the size of the `jframe` as `500,500` and size of the `jbutton` as `40,60`. However, when I executed my program, my `jbutton` was covering the whole of my `jframe`. I
tried many things and looked into many sources, but I could not find a solution.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: I suspect this should help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html but without [mcve] can't say more.

Comment: Can we see some of your code please? Is your button being added to the jFrame or a jPanel in the jFrame?

Comment: my button is being added to the jframe and not a jpanel in the jframe.

Comment: Tip: Add @Pshemo (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I'm guessing you were replying to the other comment, but Pshemo gives better advice.

Comment: `my button is being added to the jframe and not a jpanel in the jframe.` Your button is being added to the content pane of the JFrame which is a JPanel that uses a BorderLayout. You can either use "frame.add( button )" or "frame.getContentPane().add( button )". In the first case the frame adds the button to the content pane for you as a convenience. Read the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information. Keep the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Answer (score -1):

You're not using a `LayoutManager` of any kind. The `JButton` will try to inherit the size of the parent container, as the default for a JFrame is `BorderLayout` (specifically, `BorderLayout.CENTER`). You could try using

`button.setPreferredSize(x, y);`

However I don't think this would be enough by itself. Call `getContentPane` on the `Jframe`, and set a layout on that contentPane container (I use `FlowLayout` a lot, as it respects `setPreferredSize`). Put your `JButton` inside that.

This is always a good starting point:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

As the methods that you can call on a UI element vary depending on what LayoutManager you're assigning them to (be the child of). Sometimes it's `setMinimumSize`, sometimes it's `setPreferredSize`, and sometimes it's a combination.

Comment: `You're not using a LayoutManager of any kind` - yes he is that is why the button fills the entire frame. The default layout manager of the frame is a BorderLayout and be default the button is added to the BorderLayout.CENTER which resizes the component to fill all the available space on the frame. Set the layout manager of the frame to by using frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() ) to see the difference. The size of the button will be the preferred size of the button as determined by the button itself to make sure all the text is displayed.

Comment: *"You could try using

`button.setPreferredSize(x, y);`"* But x & y would be a guess. Better to alter a button's size by changing the size of the font or the margins etc.

Comment: Late reply, sorry @AndrewThompson, but the bounds were specified in the original post (60, 40). The assumption is the size is important, and not the text constraints. Depends on the purpose; there are obviously valid cases for focusing on displaying the full text. But there are times you want to design the layout of a UI, including space taken up by components. (@camickr - thanks for the correction, I forgot it defaulted to `BorderLayout`).

Comment: @Abhishek because it is a badly phrased question. You did not provide enough detail nor did you provide *any* code.